# How do you determine the size of main memory available to a program?

Tags: memory, memory-management

I'm studying topics related to virtual memory and memory allocation, but I don't really understand how to know the available memory for a process.  How do I determine the amount available; and secondly, is this determined by your operating system's kernel or is there a more architectural reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory allocated to a process is entirely dependent upon the operating environment, system, architecture, and perhaps even the underlying hardware. Even the literal detail definition of a *process* is  often dependent upon those elements. As a result, there's simply no universal answer to the question.

Comment: Also, what "available memory" *means* is platform-dependent. For example, on some platforms (including almost all modern 64-bit platforms), the memory available for file mappings may be much different from the memory available for heap space.

Comment: so to really determine how much is available for my system, a 64 bit linux environment, I'd need to experiment by allocating a large amount of space until I seg fault?

Comment: You'd probably be better served by looking into a tool called "ulimit" which provides a bunch of information on environment limits.